# SignalR issue while Scaling out azure webapp

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-backplane, signalr-service

I have existing Asp.net mvc azure webapp running on .net framework 4.6.2. I am using SignalR for real time operations. Everything works fine until I enable autoscaling. After enable autoscaling I am not getting messages everytime. I know this is because multiple website instances. I saw and tried some options to fix this i.e.

```
  (i) Service Bus
  (ii) Sql server backplane
  (iii) Redis backplane
```

Now I also heared about Azure SignalR Service.

I tried Service bus but its not working. I am also bit confused in "appName" parameter
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "appName");
is it my webapp name or service bus name ? However I tried both and not working

Secondly I tried azure signalR service. I installed required packages but I have no function with name 'app.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName)' available in Startup.cs. Not picking up any namespace reference too.

For azure signalR service :- Is It available for only .Net core?

Please help me to find a solution that is easy to implement and cost effective. I have not much traffic on my site.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the `MapAzureSignalR` method it probably means you're using the wrong package (or wrong version).

The correct package for .net Framework is `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet`

At the time of writing the Package Manager command to install is

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet -Version 1.0.0-preview1-10275
```

[Here's a link to the package on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet) that will tell you latest version which may change frequently as the package is in preview.